# Managed Configurations: defining an array of strings

Tags: android, android-for-work

According to the [restriction entry types](https://developer.android.com/work/managed-configurations.html#define-configuration), for defining a list of objects we should use the `bundle_array` type, and an example follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<restrictions xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

  <restriction
    android:key="vpn_configuration_list"
    android:restrictionType="bundle_array">
    <restriction
      android:key="vpn_configuration"
      android:restrictionType="bundle">
      <restriction
        android:key="vpn_server"
        android:restrictionType="string"/>
      <restriction
        android:key="vpn_username"
        android:restrictionType="string"/>
      <restriction
        android:key="vpn_password"
        android:restrictionType="string"/>
    </restriction>
  </restriction>

</restrictions>
```

In code that would be similar to a `List<VpnConfiguration>`, and `VpnConfiguration` would be a pojo with the three fields `vpn_server`, `vpn_username`, and `vpn_password`.

So far so good, now imagine that a simpler data structure is needed, like a `String[]`. 
According to [Test DPC](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testdpc) this should be possible, because there's an option to insert an array of strings:

[image]

Once you select it, then you are prompted to enter the list of values. However, the documentation does not have a `string_array` type, it has only the `bundle_array`.

With `bundle_array` you can define a `List<String>` instead of `String[]`, but that is overkill:

```
<restriction
    android:key="mylist"
    android:restrictionType="bundle_array">

    <restriction
        android:key="item"
        android:restrictionType="bundle">

        <restriction
            android:key="name"
            android:restrictionType="string" />

    </restriction>
</restriction>
```

So, is there a simpler way one can define a string array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `String[]` value type is only returned for the `multi-select` restriction type, for which the EMM returns a set of entries chosen among the ones you define in `android:entryValues`.

If you want to allow enterprise admin to enter a list of free-form strings then you should indeed define a `bundle_array` that contains a `string` restriction.

**Edit:** Note that `bundle_array` is only available on Android 6.0+, and there is no standard way to pass a list of free-form strings on Android 5.0/5.1. You could imagine passing a JSON within a `string` but you would need to agree with the EMM on the format of this JSON, so it wouldn't be automatically available with all EMMs.

Answer (score -1):

OK, looks like it is possible to define a string array using the same way as you would define a string:

```html
   <restriction
        android:key="my_array"
        android:restrictionType="string"
        android:title="My Array">
```

Then on the receiving part you have to make sure that you read the data as a string array:

`String[] array = restrictions.getStringArray("my_array");`

The disadvantage is that on the backend side (the EMM administration) there's no clue that the above restriction should be treated a string array and not as a String.

I have found this by testing, still not sure if this is the right way to do it...

Comment: If you define a `string` restriction like that the EMM will return a `String` value for sure. The EMM only returns a `String[]` for the `multi-select` restriction type.

Comment: Totally makes sense. Yes, for my case  a list of free-form strings are needed. Unfortunately using the `bundle_array` makes it very verbose, but I am glad you confirmed that this is the way. Thank you.

Comment: One the other hand, `bundle_array` was introduced in Android 6.0, I am wondering how was it possible to submit a list of free-form strings before that?..

Comment: That's a good point. Managed configurations were introduced in Android 5.0 and sadly it's not possible to pass a free-form list on Android 5.0/5.1, the `bundle_array` was introduced in Android 6.0 to fix this gap. You could imagine passing a JSON within a `string` restriction but you would need to agree with the EMM on the format, so it won't be available through all EMMs. I'll edit my response to add these precisions.